# Haystack says "No results found." Can't configure search form

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I try to configure Haystack, but when I enter something at search.html it says that "No results found" 
I did rebuild index and all posts were indexed.
I use Class Based Views and think that I forget something at views.py.
Thank you for any help.

My code:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255) # title of post
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(u'Дата публикации') # date of post
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000) # text of post
```

views.py

```
class MySearchView(SearchView):
    template_name = "blog/search.html"
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(MySearchView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(pub_date__gte=date(2015, 1, 1))

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MySearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

search.hmtl

```
<form type="get" action=".">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

{% if query %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No results found.</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

search_indexes.py

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    content = indexes.CharField(model_attr='content')

    def get_model(self):
        return Post

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
       return self.get_model().objects.filter(datetime__lte=timezone.now())
```

post_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.content }}
```

My source. Mb it helps

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Taa_ekRbyAWEJtcTUzaHJSSzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: in `{% for post in posts %}` try `page.object_list` instead of `posts`

Comment: nothing happens. I've added link to  my source

Comment: @OlegZagrebelsky, are you sure that there exists such post whose `pub_date` is greater that `2015, 1, 1`? Because you are searching only among such posts

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for who-ever bumps into the same problem, note that the Haystack documentation seems a little out-dated, at this time (2018). Here's a solution.

Haystack's Class-Based SearchView inherits from Django's MultipleObjectMixin, which provides the list of items in a template variable called 'object_list'.

Also, as you can read in the Haystack [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html), that the page_obj.object_list is actually a list of SearchResult objects instead of individual models.

So your template should look something like this:

```
{% if query %}
    {% for result in object_list %}
        <h1>{{ result.object.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ result.object.content }}</p>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No results found.</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```